# How to create this kind of sub-menu in new line?

Tags: menus, customization

In my design I need use this kind of wordpress custom menu.

Menu (I am able to do this)

[image]

Menu element with sub menu. (but not this one)
[image]

In this UI , I can not able to separate sub-menu to the new line with CSS. 
Then how can I add specific menu sub menu to new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, your question is similar to mine. I tried a similar thing earlier. Can check [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208407/css-2-line-menu-sub-menu-for-wordpress-modifications) started and answered by me.